# Add a feature for similarity comparison

Tags: feature-request, answers, review, duplicates

It'd be nice if answers which are an exact copy of an existing (possibly upvoted) answer or contain large substring of such an answer and few own text - which should be a comment on the copied answer - are hard to spot in review because only the question and the answer is displayed.

A warning that the above described similarity has been detected (by an algorithm which can be quite simple for starters) would be helpful and avoid that those unwanted answers get into the system/stay in there for long time as easy as possible.

Comment: I appreciate this idea, but it would be interesting for the whole SE network. You should probably propose it on [meta.se] instead of only here.

Comment: Done! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285099/add-a-feature-for-similarity-comparison